# Modal window with google oauth

Tags: oauth

I'm looking for a script, jquery or else to ask user for its google contacts, but in a nice modal window... I have the script with oauth (http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/), which works, but in a whole window...

I've tryied jquery load into a div, but it doeasn't work (nothing is loaded)...

Do you know something about this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

With jquery.load() you are running into a cross domain policy issue caused by AJAX. If you want to load the OAuth dialogue into a modal window you should load it into an iFrame within the modal window. Most popular modal window libraries support iframe content.